# Access to modules/objects within package w/o explicit import

Tags: python

Say, I have this structure on my file system: `f/o/o/bar.py`. How can I access `bar.py` contents nice & easy?
From what I can tell, I can't simply use:

```
import f #Presumably sets initial point from where to search.
print(f.o.o.bar.object)
```

In this case `import f` will seek vars inside `f`'s `__init__.py`.

When I use the code below, it works, but it seems that I have to use such imports for every module:

```
import f.o.o.bar
print(f.o.o.bar.object)
```

So, is there any easier and simpler way to work with packages, like the one below:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Athough 'argv' haven't been imported explicitly, we can access it.

P.S. It seems that the issue was with Python itself: @ 2.7.5 everything worked as it should, but @ 3.2.5, 3.3.2 he caused errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them automatically imported, then you need to specify that in the `__init__.py` files:

```
# f/__init__.py:
import o

# f/o/__init__.py:
import o

# f/o/o/__init__.py:
import bar

# f/o/o/bar.py:
object = 3
```

Then:

```
>>> import f
>>> f.o.o.bar.object
3
```

[EDIT]: The code above applies to python 2.x. Since you want to use python 3.x, you should replace each of the `import` statements above with "from . import" (which will also work with python 2.7). For example:

```
# f/__init__.py:
from . import o
```

Comment: OK, but from where I should invoke this `import`? I've put the file `tmp.py` with `import` inside `f` (in it's top dir as well), but I still get `ImportError: No module named o`... BTW, I'm calling .py from Windows command line. Here's [files](http://www.mediafire.com/?uz80fjoqhrlzgb3), just in case.

Comment: The `foo` directory must be in you python module path. So it can be a subdir in your current working directory, it can be in your `site-packages` directory (probably not a good idea) or you can set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to the parent directory of `foo`.

Comment: `tmp.py` shouldn't be *in* `f`. It should be in the directory that *contains* `f`.

Comment: Still no luck... No matter what I do it doesn't work (and I'm trying to make it work for ~4 hrs). I'll try tomorrow on virtual machine with clean OS & different version of Python.

Comment: The error suggests you are missing one of the `__init__.py` files or maybe you misnamed it (do you have double-underscores on both sides of `init`?). The error you are getting is very basic so I'm confident that using a VM or different OS won't make a difference.

Comment: @8day There's almost no chance that this is an OS or Python versioning issue; don't waste time on that stuff unless you have a concrete reason to suspect problems there.

Comment: Don't know whether it's something you knew/know, but here's a few catches: 1) module referencing modules from the same package should use relative import, like in `__init__.py`: `from . import module; print(module.object)`, 2) module referencing modules from different, topper package, should use absolute import: `import top_package; print(top_package.pack1.pack2.pack3.module.object)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a `from module import baz` statement.

```
from f.o.o.bar import baz
print baz
```

Make sure you've got an `__init__.py` file in each subdirectory, to mark those directories as packages that Python should look into. This is what my testing directory looks like:

```
C:\test\
    f\
        __init__.py # empty
        o\
            __init__.py # empty
            o\
                __init__.py # empty
                bar.py # contains the line: baz = 3
```

Then in a command window:

```
C:\test>python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from f.o.o.bar import baz
>>> baz
3
```

Note that I'm running the interpreter with `C:\test` as the working directory. Python looks in the current directory for modules and packages (in this case we want it to find the package called `f`). If you're accessing the packages/modules from somewhere else, say `C:\somewhere\else`, you need to make sure that `C:\test` (the directory containing the package) appears on your `PYTHONPATH`.

---

If you want to *automatically* import things (so you can just `import f` and get all the submodules), you can set that up in each `__init__.py` by putting import statements into those from the next directory down. Be careful when doing this, though, that you don't fill up your module namespaces with unnecessary or contradictory things.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I can't make it work. Simple imports like `from X import Y` do work, but that `f.o.o.bar` thing does not. "*don't fill up your module namespaces with unnecessary or contradictory things*" -- that's why I thought it might be a good idea to import only `f`.

Comment: @8day What *exactly* does your folder structure look like? I was able to do this in about one minute in a test directory, so I'm sure there's just something small that you're overlooking. I added my directory structure to serve as a working example.

Comment: It's `c:\Users\User\Documents\packtest2\f\o\o\bar.py`. When I emptied all `__init__.py` messages upon import went missing, but when I use `f.o` I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'o'`.

Comment: @8day You should probably read up on modules and the import statement so you understand exactly what's going on when you try different things, but for now, open a command prompt at `C:\Users\User\Documents\packtest2`, open Python, and type `from f.o.o.bar import baz` (where `baz` is something in `bar.py`). If there are no errors, then it worked. You need to just decide on one way to access things: if you only want to import `f`, your `__init__.py` files should import the things below them, so that `f\__init__.py` has access to those things.

Comment: When you type `import f`, you get access to all the things that are acecssible inside the `f\__init__.py` module, but **nothing else**. So if you might need to access everything, at every level, you can make those `__init__.py` files import the things from lower down, as in bogatron's answer. However, if all you need are certain individual items, like `f.o.o.bar.baz` (the *name* `baz` defined within the *file* `f\o\o\bar.py`), you can do `from f.o.o.bar import baz` and not have to worry about what's in the intermediate `__init__.py` files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37680/discussion-between-henry-keiter-and-8day)